# Dynamicly creating pop ups from dynamic created page - Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have created a page with Mysql rows displayed as a dynamicly created image grid.
The grid display i have full control over, but i need to take the (Mysql) Row ID from each image displayed and use it in a pop up of some sort.

I don't like having a full page for each Mysql row.

It could be passing it on to a new smaller info page(dynamic) or it could be a popup with the info(dynamic).
I would prefer the popup, since i would guess this is easier on the eyes.

So what i need a suggestion on a popup function, which will load/set the row ID on click.

I have seen Jquery solutions for making popups, but i need to pass in the variables allready set by each displayed image. and this is where i fail.

Thanks in advance.

/Niels

**
This is one of the things i have tried, but i can't really figure out the way to pass it in the right way:

```
echo "<p><a href=\"javascript:Popup('show.php?id=" .$row['user_id'] ')\">Show</a>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render the page in PHP, you could use a data attribute `<div data-mydata='foo' />` to store the ID you need. Then, with jQuery, use the data() function to access the data and render whatever popup you need.

HTML 5 data attribute: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes

jQuery Reference: http://api.jquery.com/data

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am though not really sure, how to do what you suggest. I just tried to put in some code, from which i in the pop-up can take the ID by PHP and take data from the row ID i passed on.. I though like to firstly be able to do this version correctly, but finally be able to do it the Jquery way for the better looks.

Comment: Ok, i found the solution for the problem with expressing the ID in the url (to be able to $id = $_GET['id'] on new page). On my grid page i closed the PHP and opened it again after the javascript line.